# Extract highest quality MODIS pixels in Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, modis

Based on the MYD09GA QC_500m layer description below:
MYD09GA LAYERS info QC_500m: 500m Reflectance Band Quality 
Bit 2-5: band 1 data quality four bit range 
0000 (0): highest quality

I need to extract only the highest quality data of band1. My current code is given below as well. After applying the mask, when I try to generate a chart of the timeseries for Band1, I receive the error: 
Error generating chart: Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string. 
Is something wrong with my mask function? or I need to do any data transformation for the timeseries generation? Can anyone help out please. Many thanks

```
var mod = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MYD09GA"),
geometry1 = /* color: #d63000 */ee.Geometry.Point([10.644168108701706, 64.4188479841206]);

//Selecting Band 1 and QC layers
var dataset = mod.filterDate('2013-01-01', '2013-12-31').select('sur_refl_b01','QC_500m')
var single = dataset.first()

//create mask to extract only highest quality band 1 data 
var filter = function(image){ 
var mask = single.select('QC_500m').eq(0)
return ee.Image(image).updateMask(mask)
}
var maskapply = dataset.map(filter)
var chart = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
imageCollection: maskapply, 
regions: geometry1, 
reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
scale: 1000,
band: 'sur_refl_b01',
})
print(chart)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your mask was actually masking good quality pixels out, so there was no data to plot.

Changed mask to `var mask = image.select('QC_500m').neq(0); // neq instead of eq`
Also, I think you want each mask to correspond to a particular image but not use one mask for the whole series like it was before.

So here's the new code:

```
var mod = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MYD09GA"),
geometry1 = /* color: #d63000 */ee.Geometry.Point([10.644168108701706, 64.4188479841206]);

//Selecting Band 1 and QC layers
var dataset = mod.filterDate('2013-01-01', '2013-12-31')
  .select('sur_refl_b01','QC_500m');

//create mask to extract only highest quality band 1 data 
var filter = function(image){ 
  var mask = image.select('QC_500m').neq(0);
  return ee.Image(image).updateMask(mask);
};

var maskapply = dataset.map(filter);

var chart = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
  imageCollection: maskapply, 
  regions: geometry1, 
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 1000,
  band: 'sur_refl_b01',
});

print(chart);
```

and [link to the code editor version](https://code.earthengine.google.com/01e4cd3995daa742ad37b63bcd86b971)

Comment: Thankyou Basile. :-)

Comment: You're welcome. If it solved your problem, please mark it as an answer using grey/green checkmark on the left

Comment: Hi Basile I have revisited the EE mask pages, and I think that if I was getting absolutely no data with using eq(0) in the mask, it actually meant there is no data with the quality ranking  0.  Based on this explanation on EE page:                              var mask = datamask.eq(1);                                                                                     
We use eq(1) to create a binary image in which all the pixels that do not have the value of 1 in the datamask band (those that are water or no data) get a value of 0 in the resulting image.